# They will see but will remain blind

Tags: bible, miracles, islam, non-christians

There's a verse in the Quran saying that the unbelievers will always be unbelievers because they can see the miracles, but even in this case, they won't believe.

I'm pretty sure I already read that in Christian verses, but I can't find again where I saw that.

Something like, they will see, but their eyes will be blind, they will hear, but will remain deaf.

Where did I read something like that? Which verse or text?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse-search question.

Comment: @Steve What's wrong with a verse-search question? Sometimes Google can only take you so far.

Comment: @LCIII Sorry, but the site guidelines discourages this kind of question. See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acts 28:27  (Matt 13:15 is almost identical)

> For the heart of this people is waxed gross, and their ears are dull
>   of hearing, and their eyes have they closed; lest they should see with
>   their eyes, and hear with their ears, and understand with their heart,
>   and should be converted, and I should heal them.

Romans 11:8

> (According as it is written, God hath given them the spirit of
>   slumber, eyes that they should not see, and ears that they should not
>   hear;) unto this day.

Isaiah 6:9

> And he said, Go, and tell this people, Hear ye indeed, but understand
>   not; and see ye indeed, but perceive not.

Deut. 29:4

> Yet the LORD hath not given you an heart to perceive, and eyes to see,
>   and ears to hear, unto this day.

Comment: This could usefully add Matt 13:15. Also note that both Matt and Acts explicitly credit the book of Isaiah as a source.

Comment: @disciple I tossed in a note regarding Matt 13:15, as when I compared the verses I noted how very close they are to each other.  That good enough?

Comment: +1. That's an improvement, now let's wait for @slm to decide if he or she wants to connect it to Isaiah.

Comment: Note that while similar in sound, it does not line up with the OP's interpretation, that "*unbelievers will always be unbelievers*", for the key passage which the other passages are referencing, Isaiah 6:9-13, isn't making that claim. Other parts of the Bible make a similar but slightly different and nuanced claim, when it comes to pre-destination, and other verses talk about blindness to miracles and evidence, but that Isaiah passage is quite different, despite the superficial similarity in language.

Comment: Yeah, those who think they see remain blind (John 9:41).

Answer (score 1):

“Therefore I speak to them in parables, because seeing they do not see, and hearing, they do not hear, neither do they understand.  And in them the prophecy of Isaiah is fulfilled, which says, “By hearing you will hear, and will in no way understand; Seeing you will see, and will in no way perceive: for this people’s heart has grown callous, and their ears are dull of hearing, and they have closed their eyes; or else perhaps they might perceive with their eyes, hear with their ears, understand with their heart, and should turn again; and I would heal them.  But blessed are your eyes, for they see; and your ears, for they hear.  For truly I tell you that many prophets and righteous men desired to see the things which you see, and did not see them; and to hear the things which you hear, and did not hear them” (Mat 13:13-17).  "Unless you people see signs and wonders," Jesus told him, "you will never believe." John 4:48